# Cannot rotate text d3js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, label, sunburst-diagram

I'm trying to add text to the [partition-sunburst example](http://bl.ocks.org/4063423). I have followed a hint given on Google Group and I was able to add the text. Now I want to rotate it. The new angles seem to be correct, but all the text get gathered in one point.

This is the piece of code where I add and rotate the text:

```js
var text = vis.data([json]).selectAll("text")
    .data(partition.nodes)
      .enter().append("svg:text")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return radius * Math.cos(d.x + d.dx/2); } )
        .attr("y", function(d) { return radius * Math.sin(d.x + d.dx/2); } )
        .attr("dy", ".31em")
        .style("font-size", "5px")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          var angle = (2 * Math.PI - d.x) * (180/Math.PI);
          var rotation = "rotate(" + angle + ")";
          console.log(rotation);
          console.log("d.x=" + d.x + ", d.y=" + d.y);
          return rotation;
        })
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```

This is an image of what I get:

[image]

and this is the full script:

```js
var width = 1000,
    height = 1000,
    radius = 350,
    x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, 2 * Math.PI]),
    y = d3.scale.pow().exponent(1.3).domain([0, 1]).range([0, radius]),
    padding = 5,
    color = d3.scale.category20c();

var vis = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var partition = d3.layout.partition()
    .sort(null)
    .size([2 * Math.PI, radius * radius])
    .value(function(d) { return 1; });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(function(d) { return d.x; })
    .endAngle(function(d) { return d.x + d.dx; })
    .innerRadius(function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.y); })
    .outerRadius(function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.y + d.dy); });

d3.json("fracking.json", function(json) {
  var path = vis.data([json]).selectAll("path")
      .data(partition.nodes)
    .enter().append("svg:path")
      .attr("display", function(d) { return d.depth ? null : "none"; })
      // hide inner ring
      .attr("d", arc)
      .attr("fill-rule", "evenodd")
      .style("stroke", "#fff")
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name); })
  .each(stash);

   var text = vis.data([json]).selectAll("text")
    .data(partition.nodes)
      .enter().append("svg:text")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return radius * Math.cos(d.x + d.dx/2); } )
        .attr("y", function(d) { return radius * Math.sin(d.x + d.dx/2); } )
        .attr("dy", ".31em")
        .style("font-size", "5px")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          var angle = (2 * Math.PI - d.x) * (180/Math.PI);
          var rotation = "rotate(" + angle + ")";
          console.log(rotation);
          console.log("d.x=" + d.x + ", d.y=" + d.y);
          return rotation;
        })
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  d3.select("#size").on("click", function() {
    path
        .data(partition.value(function(d) { return d.size; }))
      .transition()
        .duration(1500)
        .attrTween("d", arcTween);
    d3.select("#size").classed("active", true);
    d3.select("#count").classed("active", false);
  });
  d3.select("#count").on("click", function() {
    path
        .data(partition.value(function(d) { return 1; }))
      .transition()
        .duration(1500)
        .attrTween("d", arcTween);
    d3.select("#size").classed("active", false);
    d3.select("#count").classed("active", true);
  });
});

// Stash the old values for transition.
function stash(d) {
  d.x0 = d.x;
  d.dx0 = d.dx;
}

// Interpolate the arcs in data space.
function arcTween(a) {
  var i = d3.interpolate({x: a.x0, dx: a.dx0}, a);
  return function(t) {
    var b = i(t);
    a.x0 = b.x;
    a.dx0 = b.dx;
    return arc(b);
  };
}
```

Comment: You should create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for your example when asking questions like this. It makes it easier for people answering questions to see your code example working live and easily editable.

Comment: Question is about rotating text. The type of diagram being made does not matter. Please do not add that tag back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to specify the center of rotation. Try this:

```
var text = vis.data([json]).selectAll("text")
.data(partition.nodes)
  .enter().append("svg:text")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return radius * Math.cos(d.x + d.dx/2); } )
    .attr("y", function(d) { return radius * Math.sin(d.x + d.dx/2); } )
    .attr("dy", ".31em")
    .style("font-size", "5px")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      var angle = (2 * Math.PI - d.x) * (180/Math.PI);
      var rotation = "rotate(" + angle + "," + d3.select(this).attr("x") + "," d3.select(this).attr("y") +")";
      console.log(rotation);
      console.log("d.x=" + d.x + ", d.y=" + d.y);
      return rotation;
    })
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```